# Displaying enumerated type

Tags: c++, enums

Alright so this is my display function, and the enumerated type associated with it.

```
enum EventType {ARRIVAL = 'A', DEPARTURE = 'D'};    


void EventList::display()
{
cout << "Event List: ";
for (ListNode *cur = head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
{
    if (cur->item.type == ARRIVAL)
        cout << ARRIVAL << cur->item.beginTime << ":" << cur->item.transactionLength << " ";
    else if (cur->item.type == DEPARTURE)
        cout << DEPARTURE << cur->item.beginTime << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

}

The problem with this is that the output I want is for it to display the A or the D. Not the integer values associated with the letters. How exactly do I do this?

```
Event List: 652:5 686
```

I want that to read

```
Event List: A2:5 D6
```

Comment: Are you aware, that an `enum` is actually a number and assigning `'A'` to `ARRIVAL` will actually assign the ASCII code of `A`?

Comment: @KirilKirov: the chance of such a question arising naturally is ~0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: cast it to a `char`:

```
cout << char(ARRIVAL) << cur->item.beginTime << ":" << cur->item.transactionLength << " ";
```

The same for `DEPARTURE`.

The reason why it works this way is that when used in an expression, enumerations are normally promoted to `int` (or a larger integral type if their values don't fit into an `int`). You have the correct `char` value inside the enum, however, so you can just cast it.

Comment: Thank you! That was all I needed to finally finish about 5 hours of programming.